# How should unsubscribe be handled in a react component when using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my component I have the following:

```
componentWillMount: function () {
  this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(function () {
    this.setState({message: store.getState().authentication.message});
  }.bind(this));
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
  this.unsubscribe();
},
```

Not calling unsubscribe causes the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

What I'd like to know is should I be assigning `unsubscribe` to `this` or is there a better place to assign it?

Comment: You should try in componentDidMount() instead of componentWillMount().

Comment: @legolandbridge that doesn't make any difference as I still need to `unsubscribe`.

Comment: Have you looked into using `react-redux`'s `connect` and `Provider`?

Comment: And assigning to `this` is perfectly fine. I have a bias against it, though, but that doesn't change the fact that, with React, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by [Salehen Rahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538570/salehen-rahman) above in the comments I did end up using [react-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux).

Following their documentation I created two functions, one to map the 'global state' to the props within the component:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users.items
  };
}
```

and one to map the dispatched actions to functions passed into the component as props:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    lockUser: (id) => dispatch(actions.lockUser(id)),
    unlockUser: (id) => dispatch(actions.unlockUser(id)),
    updateUser: (id, user) => dispatch(actions.updateUser(id, user)),
    addUser: (user) => dispatch(actions.addUser(user))
  };
}
```

This then all gets pulled together using the `connect` method:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer);
```

I have a feeling that all this does under the hood is attach the `unsubscribe` method to the component but it does simplify things substantially.

Comment: Under the hood it indeed attaches `unsubscribe` to `this`—but not your component. React Redux `connect()` generates an intermediate component: that's why you receive data as `this.props`, and not as `this.state`. You should probably use React Redux in most cases instead of hand-rolling it because it has certain performance optimizations.

Comment: It also uses the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/72ed6db/src/components/Provider.js#L17-L26