# Should I use properties (other than props or state) in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering if I should use properties (not props, not state) in React component?

For example,

```
var myComponent = React.createClass ({
    _text: '',   // Something like this, a property other than props or state
});
```

What are the pros and cons, and what are the use cases?

Comment: To my experience almost everything that you can do with properties, you can do with `state`.

Comment: @SalehenRahman But setState would cause re-render as side effect if I'm not wrong?

Comment: I asked a question that's related here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372646/how-should-unsubscribe-be-handled-in-a-react-component-when-using-redux. So that's one possible use case.

Comment: If a value is used in the render use state. If it is only used in the methods use a property.

Comment: @YiFeng I said almost. There are cases when it's necessary. Such as resource cleanup as mentioned by Clarkie.

Comment: @JanakaStevens YiFeng was talking about a third option: class properties. There's `state` and `props` which are features offered by React. And then there's JavaScript class properties (albeit, we made that term up to help us be in line with paradigms borrowed from OO languages). It is very tempting to say that class properties are useless with React, but there has yet to be an argument against it; YiFeng wants to know if there are any arguments against properties. So far there's more for it than against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Properties are great for storing data that isn't related to the view, but useful for modifying behaviour.**

Why not `state` or `props`? `state` should ideally be modified when calling `setState`. But calling `setState` also calls `render`, leading to performance overheads. Although, we can cancel the `render` call by overriding `componentShouldUpdate`, but that's making things too complicated. So, `state` is not the best place. `props` seems like a good candidate, but, it can be over-written beyond our control, so that's not ideal either.

An example use case: you have a resource allocated in `componentDidMount`, that needs to be cleaned up. The best place to do that would be in `componentWillUnmount`. But how would you keep tabs of which resource was allocated? You use properties.

```
React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    // `allocateResource` is entirely made up, but functions like it exist.
    this.someResourcePointer = allocateResource();
  },

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // `deallocateResource` is also entirely made up.
    deallocateResource(this.someResourcePointer);
  },

  render() {
    return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
  }
});
```

Some real-world examples:

- subscribing to and unsubscribing from event emitters
- having a pool of canvas contexts, if you need to spawn multiple canvas contexts