# Redux unsubscribe within componentWillUnmount still calls subscribe callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am manually hooking a React component up to a Redux store. Yes, I realize Dan Abramov of Redux [recommends against this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372646/#comments-32428568). I will be getting around to looking at react-redux eventually, but for now I want to understand what's going on.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
        const storeState = store.getState();
        this.setState({
            someData: storeState.someData
        });
    }.bind(this));
}
componentWillUnmount () {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

This is some code I have in a tab  page component. These tab pages get swapped in and out in a parent component as the user changes tabs to display different data. I have stepped through the debugger and confirmed that as a user changes tabs, the following occurs in order:

1. The previous tab is unmounted (`componentWillUnmount` fires and `this.unsubscribe()` is called. `this` is the previous tab component, as expected)
2. The new tab is mounted. (`componentDidMount` fires and `this` is the new tab component, as expected)
3. `setState` gets called in the subscribe callback with `this` being the PREVIOUS TAB, and react complains with an error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Tab component.

This seems strange to me. Shouldn't calling `unsubscribe` as I have prevent this callback from being called on the unmounted component? The [post that I'm following along with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372646) seems to suggest that doing what I've done should make this warning go away, and is simply questioning if this is a good idea. But in my case, it persists.

I don't think it matters, but I am using the ES6 "class" syntax whereas the original appears not to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subscribe(listener: () => void): Unsubscribe;
```

Lets read subscribe method doc.

> 1. The subscriptions are snapshotted just before every `dispatch()` call.
>      If you subscribe or unsubscribe while the listeners are being invoked,
>      this will not have any effect on the `dispatch()` that is currently in
>      progress. However, the next `dispatch()` call, whether nested or not,
>      will use a more recent snapshot of the subscription list.

Since you first have called dispatch method, all listeners are invoken and your unsubsribe call will only take place on next dispatch call.